# # error throw by jquery in vue

Tags: jquery, laravel

I m new to vue please help me what i m doing wrong
here is my welcome blade

```
 <!doctype html>
  <html lang="{{ app()->getLocale() }}">
     <head>
         <meta charset="utf-8">
         <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
         <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">     

          <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{asset('homepage/images/favicon.ico')}}">     

         <title>Minton - Responsive Admin Dashboard & Frontend</title>     

         <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,500' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
         <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>     

         <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
         <link href="{{asset('homepage/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">     

         <!-- Animate -->
         <link href="{{asset('homepage/css/animate.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">     

         <!-- Icon-font -->
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{asset('homepage/css/themify-icons.css')}}">     

         <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
         <link href="{{asset('homepage/css/style.css')}}" rel="stylesheet">

     </head>
     <body>
       <div id="app">

       </div>
       <script src="{{asset('js/app.js')}}"></script>

         <script src="{{asset('homepage/js/popper.min.js')}}"></script>
         <script src="{{asset('homepage/js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
         <!-- Jquery easing -->
         <script type="text/javascript" src="{{asset('homepage/js/jquery.easing.1.3.min.js')}}">
       </script>
         <script src="{{asset('homepage/js/SmoothScroll.js')}}"></script>
         <script src="{{asset('homepage/js/wow.min.js')}}"></script>
         <script src="{{asset('homepage/js/jquery.waypoints.min.js')}}" type="text/javascript">
       </script>
         <script src="{{asset('homepage/js/jquery.counterup.min.js')}}" type="text/javascript">
       </script>     

         <!--common script for all pages-->
         <script src="{{asset('homepage/js/jquery.app.js')}}"></script>     

         <script type="text/javascript">
             jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                 $('.counter').counterUp({
                     delay: 100,
                     time: 1200
                 });
             });
         </script>
     </body>
 </html>
```

in welcome vue page i have login button

```
           <li class="nav-item">
          <router-link :to="'/login'" class="nav-link" exact><i class="icon-puzzle"></i> 
              Login</router-link>
        </li>
```

all above code work properly but don't know why it throw  Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #/login in jquery
 if yes how i can solve this kind of issue url like this localhost/vue/public/#/login moreover if i refresh the page issue gone is this jquery issue or vue.

Comment: try `:to="/login"` with only the one set of quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The single quotes enclosed by the double quotes are un-neccessary in the router-link.

`<router-link :to="/login"></router-link>`

or

```
<router-link :to='/login'></router-link>
```